# How to force UITableViewCell selection using selectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to force selection(highlight) of a UITableViewCell using selectRowAtIndexPath..

For eg,
Lets say i want to always have the first cell in a table view to be highlighted,I apply the following logic in viewDidAppear

```
[self.tableViewPrompts selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
```

Works nicely.But when i try to apply the same logic elsewhere in the application the cell is not selected.I even tried deselecting other cells before calling the above method and reloading tableview before and after calling this method but none of the approaches seem to work!

I even used the tableview's delegate to forcibly make a call to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.Event this does not work.

PS: The selection of the cell does not trigger any action all i am trying to achieve is highlighting the desired cell.

What am i doing wrong here?

Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Make sure you aren't calling reloadData after selectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The selection of the cell does not trigger any action all i am trying to achieve is highlighting the desired cell.

Why don't you use the cell's highlighted property?

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0]];
cell.highlighted = YES;
```

Cant test it now, but it should work.....

**edit**

Better yet, of course: change your cellForRowAtIndexPath to do that

```
-(UITableViewCell) tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
//...
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) cell.highlighted = YES
else cell.highlighted = NO;
//...
return cell;
```

Comment: This was just what I needed. You'd think that selectRowAtIndexPath would do this for you... :P

Comment: Be warned that simply setting a cell's `highlighted` property does not make the cell "selected" from the perspective of the parent table view. It just changes the appearance of the cell. If that's all you want, then this is fine.

Comment: In this question from 2013, the OP stated "all i am trying to achieve is highlighting the desired cell" - so that should be clear

Comment: I had this problem, and fixed it when I discovered the UITableView attributes inspector showed "Selection" was somehow set to "none".  It worked when set to "Single Selection".

Answer (score 3):

I'm puzzled why isn't this working in your case. Here is my method I use from several places inside my view controller including `viewDidAppear` and I see no real difference with what you're doing:

```
- (void)selectRow1
{
    NSIndexPath* idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    [_table selectRowAtIndexPath:idx animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    [self tableView:_table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:idx];
}
```

`_table` is my table property variable, and the call to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is made so the action of selection could happen but otherwise the only real difference with your code is the scrollPosition parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use setSelected to highlight cell:

```
  [cell setSelected:YES];
```

I have created this extension for the whole purpose [UITableView-Ext](https://github.com/aqibmumtaz/UITableView-Ext)